# Add Log entry on Model Export Actions

Tags: python, django, import, export-to-csv, openai-api

I have enabled Log entries in the Django Admin

```
class CustomLogEntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [
        "action_time",
        "user",
        "content_type",
        "object_id",
        "object_repr",
        "action_flag",
        "change_message",
    ]
    # list filter
    list_filter = ["action_time", "user", "content_type"]

    # search
    search_fields = ["user__username", "object_repr"]


admin.site.register(LogEntry, CustomLogEntryAdmin)
```

And I have another model whose admin.py code is like this

```
class RegAdmin(ExportActionMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = RegAdminResource

    def has_view_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_permission(self, request):
        return True
```

By default all change, addition and deletion entries are logged but I also want to log an entry when any export action is performed on it. ChatGPT suggests that I should something like this

```
    # in admin class 
    def export_action(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Log the export action
        LogEntry.objects.create(
            user_id=request.user.id,
            content_type_id=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.model).id,
            object_id=None,
            object_repr=str(self.model),
            action_flag=1,  # Assuming 1 stands for the action flag of 'change'
            change_message="Export action triggered.",
        )
        return super().export_action(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

But this function is not triggered when an export action is performed. I confirmed by adding a print statement.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quite close, the only problem is that the actions have reference to the one defined in the `ExportActionMixin`, so you can override whatever you want, it is not going to refer to your method. You can however override that to to get the right action, so:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _


class RegAdmin(ExportActionMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    # …
    
    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super().get_actions(request)
        actions.update(
            export_admin_action=(
                RegAdmin.export_admin_action,
                'export_admin_action',
                _('Export selected %(verbose_name_plural)s'),
            )
        )
        return actions
```

**Update**: I've opened a [*pull request* <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/pull/1681) to fix this behavior.

Comment: @SamiMalik: I've opened a [pull request](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/pull/1681) such that overriding `get_actions` will (hopefully) no longer be necessary in the future.

Comment: Awesome. That would be great!

Comment: This has been fixed in django-import-export rel 3.3.3